# Determine the name of the local Administrators group in Vista

Tags: language-agnostic, windows-vista

How can I determine the name of the local Administrators group in Vista? This can vary depending on the operating system language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look it up by the well known SID.

In .NET you can use the enum value: `System.Security.Principal.BuiltinAdministratorsSid`

In Win32 you can use the enum value: `WELL_KNOWN_SID_TYPE.WinBuiltinAdministratorsSid` and see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379649(VS.85).aspx) for details.

Answer (score 2):

As Richard proposes, use the wellknown sid to find the group.

```
var adminGroupSid = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-32-544");
var adminGroup = (NTAccount)adminGroupSid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
var adminGroupName = adminGroup.Value;
```